# Get large data set in small pieces to save memory?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a "huge" result set from an SQL query. About 2-3 million rows of a column of type varchar(50). This might not be too big to be worried about. But, what if I have to process 
10-15 such columns ?

So, that brings me to my question - Is there a way to retrieve a huge amount of data in small chunks using SQL, put them into memory, do processing with whichever language/tool you wish (I use C# and SSIS ETL tool) ?

If you feel this question needs to be clearer, please put a comment.

Comment: If possible, use a *streaming* access method (e.g. SqlReader or IQueryable) - work with the data as it comes in, but don't materialize the entire result-set at once (e.g. don't read into a DataTable or force to a List).

Comment: @user2864740 - work with the data as it comes in - What does this mean ? How does this work in principle ? Is it like this - You ask for 2 Million rows, then SS retrieves, say 20,000 and returns them to you. After that it looks for more records till it reaches the 2 million mark ?

Comment: There is *streaming* and there is *paging*. As long as the query itself is able to stream, SQL Server (and the ADO.NET in C#) will quite happily stream the data for usage - you'll get all the records, one after other. As soon as a materialization is forced (such as reading into a DataTable), then the code has to wait for *all* results to come in. However, if we simply write out to a file immediately .. then each record can be processed as it comes.

Comment: @user2864740 - how do I know that a query can be streamed ?

Comment: Generally by running it :) The result-set (say millions of rows) can still be streamed such as it does not need to be materialized on the client, even if a query has to run for X minutes before returning the first result (in which case poor SQL is running over itself building lots of intermediate data). However, most queries oriented to streaming should start returning results immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @PageN int = 0  -- 0..N
DECLARE @RowPerPage int = 20

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [LastLoginDate]) as rowNumber
        ,Customer.*
    FROM dbo.Customer
    --WHERE <Search cond>
    ) paging
WHERE rowNumber > @PageN * @RowPerPage
    AND rowNumber <= (@PageN + 1) * @RowPerPage;
```

Paging for MS SQL 2008

Comment: Can you explain what the code is doing, ie brief description ? I am new to these things so, I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: @blasto, I do not know C # and I can not give you the code. But if you show your sql query I can help to change it for paging. The idea of ​​paging selection. At first, you try the page number is 0. You get 20 rows and process them. Request to the next page. If you get a rows less then 20 (or 0), then you have reached the end of the data

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. In C# you can use LINQ and as long as you iterate over the results (and avoid calling `ToList()` or something similar) the rows from the resultset will be loaded one at a time. If you're not using LINQ, you can use a SqlDataReader instead.