# How to handle "big data" or "large data" with SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, data-warehouse, etl

I am running dynamic queries that often return HUGE (300MB - 1GB) result sets initially. Later, it should not be this big (not sure about that though) because I will be using delta loading. These result sets are then loaded into a C# data table. A script loops over these rows and then generates a query (stored in SSIS variable) to load them to the appropriate destination columns (determined by other scripts).

For small result sets, my package runs properly. But, for big ones, it simply fails due to out of memory error. 
How do I resolve this problem ? Can you suggest some strategies ? I guess I could fetch smaller parts of the data at a time and then load into target. Not sure how to go about it though. Is there a recipe for this ?

A brief intro to how the process works -

```
Execute SQL: Get big ResultSet > Script:RowReader: Read each row 
and generate a String SQL like "Insert INTO TableABC VALUES" + {all 
columns of 1 row here}. Then, concatenate SQL to a String destinationInsert > 
Execute SQL: execute SQL inside String destinationInsert.
```

ETL process complete. Does that help ?

Comment: Can you move the script into SQL code and save the problem of moving the data from the server to the application?

Comment: Can the processing be done without "loading into .. data table .. variables"? SQL Server is good at what it is capable of doing.

Comment: @user2864740 - no. each row is read and then its columns are appended into a string which contains Insert into(something) Values(something + {what ever you read from row goes here}). This is done for all rows. Then, this super big insert string is fed into the destination table.

Comment: @blasto Icky! Anyway .. if this is done per-row, can the operation be *streamed* (e.g. SqlDataReader)? Or can the transformation (per the application rules) be generated as [dynamic] SQL which can then be executed directly?

Comment: Downvoter, please tell me why the -1. If you need more info, please tell me.

Comment: You need to post more details about your process.

Comment: @Zane - okay. i did that. Does it make sense now ?

Comment: What value is SSIS bringing to the table for you? As I'm reading this question, I can't help but think SSIS is not the right tool for you on this job.

Answer (score 4):

As T-SQL is a proper programming language, there is a lot you can do with it. If the 'script' you mentioned does not involve heavy I/O or remote communication, it could be rewritten in SQL.

Data is usually treated row-by-row and that is something which can be done with one single statement (UPDATE...). So in any case you will be able to do what you want inside the server.

But let's assume the script is too complex to code it in SQL. Well, then code it in C# add the assembly into SQL-Server. Your C# code will be accessible as a CLR function and so you can do everything without blowing up the memory. Edit: Ooops, you're using SQL-2005. Not 100% sure if you can add .NET assemblies... As Gary Walker pointed out, CLR is supported in SQL 2005. Thx, Gary.

If you share your script or at least the basic functionality of it with us, I am sure we can find a fast and easy solution for you.

Comment: would paging be helpful here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553945/get-large-data-set-in-small-pieces-to-save-memory ?

Comment: @blasto If it's per-row, just *stream* (e.g. use SqlDataReader or appropriate IEnumerable source) and skip the DataTables entirely. Streaming only asks for the data once - but processes it one row at a time. Of course, if the code is greatly invested in DataTables then, depending on exactly what is occurring (*this is important!*), paging may be a workaround to the immediate problem.

Comment: SQL 2005 was the first version to support CLR assemblies.

Comment: @user2864740 - can you help me to figure out if paging might be the solution for me in this situation ?

Comment: @blasto Try it. Does it work correctly. Does it work reliably? :) We don't have transparency into the entire process.

Comment: @user2864740 - yes, I can give you more information if possible. btw, i added a basic description of the process to my question. Will that be enough to help me decide if paging is a solution ? Thanks.

Comment: @blasto Go for it - and report back! (Do be aware that this change may affect ACid properties that have been relied upon unless wider transactions are used!)